# python win32com "PumpWaitingMessages()" processing

Tags: python, python-3.x, com, win32com

I use `Python 3.4`. I have a program that provide an integration with `COM` module in Windows, by `win32com` package. To process messages from this module I use the `pythoncom.PumpWaitingMessages()` method in the infinite `while` loop. But python infinite loop makes 100% CPU core load (as shown in Windows Task Manager). The questions:

1. Is it real "work" or peculiarity of Windows Task Manager?
2. How one can avoid that. Maybe by using `asyncio` module or another way?
3. Is it possible to process messages in another thread or asynchronously with `pythoncom`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PumpWaitingMessage` will process messages and return as soon as there are no more messages to process.

You can call it in a loop, but you should call `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects`, or `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx`, before the next loop iteration.

Avoid calling these functions before the initial loop iteration, as they'll block and you won't have a chance to see if some condition is met whether there are messages to process or not.  Or alternatively, provide a reasonable timeout to these functions.